# Параллельная запись и чтение из файла linux

Tags: linux, bash

Я через `nc` слушаю порт и пишу все, что приходит в файл.

```
nc -v  $ip $port > out.txt
```

Это висист основным потоком в скрипте.
В параллельном потоке с этим раз в 5 секунд я делаю копию файла out.txt и проверяю, есть ли именения за эти 5 секунд.

```
if [ "$(diff out.tmp out.txt)" ]
then
    cat out.txt > out.tmp
    sleep 5
else
    #something
fi
```

Могут ли испортиться данные которые я получаю через `nc`? И если такая вероятность есть, то как ее уменьшить или избежать? Поток приходящих данных контролировать я не могу.

Comment: данные вряд ли испортятся. Но вот только если файл будет большой, то копирование будет долго. Может просто `tail -f` использовать?

Comment: @KoVadim а как тут `tail -f` использовать?

Comment: @KoVadim да, мне же не нужно весь файл хранить, а только последнюю строчку и смотреть изменилась она или нет. Думаю за время копирования 1-й строки из файла  вероятность порчи  данных крайне мала

Comment: для размышления https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309453/bash-tail-f-with-while-read-and-pipe-hangs

Comment: @KoVadim а Вы не знаете где можно на системном уровне почитать как работает cat и файловые дескрипторы? В моей голове это 100% должно портить данные, а это почему-то работает.

Comment: cat просто открывает файл на чтение выводит на стандартный вывод. Файл при этом не изменяется. В Вашем случае потом эти данные попадают в другой файл. Что там должно портится - не знаю

Comment: @SkiF зачем, же вы cat ом копируете...? сравнивайте два выхлопа от nc сразу без промежуточного файла.

Comment: почему не `nc -v $ip $port | something`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сабпрцессы ваш лучший друг.

Пример с `date`:

```
~$ diff <(date) <(sleep 3;date)
--- /proc/self/fd/63
+++ /proc/self/fd/62
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Fri Feb  9 22:00:24 GMT 2018
+Fri Feb  9 22:00:27 GMT 2018
```

И добавим условие:

```
~$ if ! diff <(date) <(sleep 3;date) >/dev/null; then echo "changed"; fi
changed
```

> да, мне же не нужно весь файл хранить, а только последнюю строчку и
>   смотреть изменилась она или нет.

Пример `nc`

```
$ diff <(nc -v $host $port) <(sleep 5; nc -v $host $port)
```

Можете добавить временную метку и поставить на `cron` или в бесконечный цикл.

Пример готового решения:

```
#/use/bin/env bash

host=$1
port=$2

if ! diff <(nc -v $host $port) <(sleep 5; nc -v $host $port) >/dev/null; then
    printf "[%s]  changed\n" "$(date)"
else
    printf "[%s]  ok\n" "$(date)"
fi

# End of script
```

В цикле:

```
while true; do ./script.sh 123.456.789 12| tee -a monitor.log; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не сделать так:

```
function process {
    for line in $(nc -v  $ip $port); do
       process_line $line
    done
}

process &
```

---

Еще можно создать очередь на именованом канале, чтобы вообще получить межпроцессорное взамодействие.

Comment: Это работает медленне чем простой кат в файл. Мне это не подходит